# Calculate sum by each category in Power Bi Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the total recipe cost price for each recipe. I used the below DAX formula as shown in the image but I am not getting the correct result.

[image]

Comment: How many tables do you use? Is Recipe Name in pivot table column from table `All Recipes`? And why are values in Column1 empty?

Comment: I have only 1 table. I am newbie. My table name is All recipes. Please ignore column 1 and column 2. The column headings are recipe name and ingredient cost price. There are almost 3000 recipes in All Recipes table. I have only listed 2 recipes.

Comment: Post realistic, copiable data, not a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumign your data looks like this

### Table: AllRecipes

| Recipe Name | Ingredient Cost Price |
| --- | --- |
| 112 Apple & Cinnamon Crumble | 0.01 |
| 112 Apple & Cinnamon Crumble | 0.03 |
| 112 Apple & Cinnamon Crumble | 0.05 |
| 112 Apple & Cinnamon Crumble | 0.17 |
| 112 Apple & Cinnamon Crumble | 0.23 |
| 113 Banana Pancake | 0 |
| 113 Banana Pancake | 0 |
| 113 Banana Pancake | 0.01 |
| 113 Banana Pancake | 0.18 |

Try the following calculation:

### Dax Calculation: Recipe Total Cost Price

```
Recipe Total Cost Price =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( AllRecipes[Ingredient Cost Price] ),
    ALL ( AllRecipes[Ingredient Cost Price] )
)
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you but this didn't work for me. It's still not giving me the total value. I am trying to do this in a pivot table and this aggregation is required in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Not something like this?
Recipe---(1,M)--ProductIngredient(WeightKG)---(M,1)--Ingredient

Per Recipe Cost = CALCULATE(SUMX('ProductIngredient', [IngredientWeight_Kg] *
RELATED('Ingredient'[Price per Kg])
)
)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).